# Migrating new Word Press to a different CPanel account with old site on it

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, backup, cpanel, migrating

I was charged by a client to build a new Wordpress that will replace an old website built with a custom CMS.

I built the WordPress on a different CPanel user and sub domain. It is currently (the new site) on http://alpha.mywebsite.com while the old site is directly at http://www.mywebsite.com.

What would be the best way to do this?

In a perfect scenario, I would change the public_html folder in the main domain to public_html_old, and copy the new one containing the wordpress to public_html.

Is this safe practice? Or is there additional database, admin, etc. stuff I need to be aware of?

Thanks a lot for your tips and opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider update URLs in database too. One of the safest and easiest way to migrate your WordPress to a new domain is using "[Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)". it backs up your wordpress files and database, then you move the backup files to new domain and run the duplicator's installer file. it updates all urls.

Comment: Hello!

What do you think I should do to the old CMS if i want to keep it as a backup? Perhaps just compress the Public HTML folder?

I will look into the plugin :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can ideally transfer old site to a folder called oldcms (http://www.mywebsite.com.).
2. After successfully transferring old site to oldcms folder, transfer wordpress site to public_html folder, after doing this you will have to change url(from http://alpha.mywebsite.com to http://www.mywebsite.com) in database table called wp_options -> under option name column -> siteurl & home.
3. After successfully transeferring the new site(wordpress) install https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ for url updating.

this way you know that your old cms is in 'oldcms' folder and new site is in public_html. Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes it sounds like the steps i needed. I might update you since I am planning to do all of this tonight